# Flash drive friendly (portable) XAMPP alternative?

Tags: apache-http-server, php, mysql, shutdown

I'm trying to setup a portable MediaWiki wiki on a flash drive using XAMPP portable as a server.

http://lifehacker.com/354005/run-your-personal-wikipedia-from-a-usb-stick

When I try to start apache or mySQL I get this error ([paste](http://pastebay.net/1333362)).

```
11:19:52 AM [Apache] Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
11:19:52 AM [Apache] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
11:19:52 AM [Apache] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:19:52 AM [Apache] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:19:52 AM [Apache] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:19:52 AM [Apache] If you need more help, copy and post this
11:19:52 AM [Apache] entire log window on the forums
```

I've tried suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440727/apache-shutdown-unexpectedly) to fix the problem. I've tried doing it on a different computer (a different computer in my house, so using the same internet connection) and with older versions of XAMPP. All to no avail. I had apache and mySQL running before but deleted that folder to start fresh after messing up the wiki settings on a new wiki I had made.

How do I fix my problem with XAMPP? I have to use MediaWiki - I'm not interested in tiddlywiki or any alternatives that don't require its own sever, for my needs it has to be MediaWiki. The issue is with the server anyway.

edit:

Since I can't get XAMPP to work I'm going to go with mowes portable instead. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "When I try to start apache or mySQL" - you get Apache errors when you start MySQL? What does it say above that log entry?

Comment: Sorry I wasen't very clear. Here is the full error log http://pastebay.net/1333362

Comment: I'm not *too* familiar with XAMPP, but are there other logs? The part "Press the Logs button to view error logs" seems to suggest there are.

Comment: When I click logs it says "logs not found, do you want to create a new file?" <-not word for word btw.

Comment: No idea why it doesn't work. Maybe something like [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/) would be more suited and more light-weight.

Comment: is this on windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Wiki-on-a-stick](http://stickwiki.sourceforge.net/).

The Syntax is somewhat different from Mediawiki, but for my purposes, it was OK (Basically, keep notes in a structured way).

The whole Wiki is a self-contained XHTML file. It lives wherever you put it and is run by your browser. No special software needed!

(Hint: It creates lots of backups of itself - have a fast USB drive or make backups manually and disable them in the tool. When it grows over time, it can end up slowing down its own operation considerably)

Answer (score 0):

This mature project - [Denwer](http://www.denwer.ru/) works from USB flash, the only issue that the website is all in Russian. Automatic [translation](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&u=http://www.denwer.ru/) by Google

> The main feature of Denver - convenience when working remotely on
>   several independent projects and the possibility of placing a
>   Flash-Drive

Direct [download](http://www.denwer.ru/dis/Base/127001/Denwer3_Base_2013-06-02_a2.2.22_p5.3.13_m5.5.25_pma3.5.1_xdebug.exe) of current version

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Uniform Server for a long time for this purpose. The versions of Uniform Server that seems to meet your criterion is [MiniServers_MediaWiki](http://sourceforge.net/projects/miniserver/files/MiniServer/MiniServers_%20MediaWiki/), which is a version of Uniform Server with MediaWiki pre-installed. Otherwise you can try the generic servers: either Coral or ZeroXI. More information is available through the Uniform Server [wiki](http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/Main_Page).

I am not connected with Uniform Server in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The Best XAMPP Alternative that is portable that I have used is a program called [EasyPHP DevServer](http://www.easyphp.org/easyphp-devserver.php). It's free and compatible with Windows.

This does not need administrative rights so you can load this straight off a USB stick without needing permissions.